# Unable to mount the file system from server to client while booting through network

Tags: nfs, mount, boot, pxe-boot

I want a client which loads kernel and file system from the server through network.

Till now, On server side, i changed the settings in /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf to get an ip-address to the client. After that i executed service isc-dhcp-server restart command.

I built openwrt kernel image openwrt-x86-generic-vmlinuz by downloading necessary packages

I created one directory with name /tftpboot and i copied pxelinux.0 from /usr/lib/pxelinux.0 to /tftpboot

And i also copied openwrt-x86-generic-vmlinuz in /tftpboot

Inside /tftpboot i created one directory with name pxelinux.cfg

Now vim /tftpboot/pxelinux.cfg/default:

default openwrt
label openwrt
kernel openwrt-x86-generic-vmlinuz
append boot=nfs root=/dev/nfs nfsroot=nfs:server-ip:/tftpboot ip=dhcp rw

Now i executed command service tftpd-hpa restart

At client side , i restarted system and i selected the boot options to pxe booting

It is loading the kernel openwrt-x86-generic-vmlinuz smoothly . Not mounting the file system which i had given in /etc/exports file

Now my question is how can i mount the filesystem from server to client while booting

Any mistakes in boot arguments ?

or any other method to mount file system while booting

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

your boot process sure calls an init script, you have to add the NFS mount on that script.
The init script will receive the variables passed to the kernel at boot time, among the ones you find the NFS mounting parameters.